# Drupal local site very slow on wampserver

Tags: drupal-7, wampserver

I have two locations for "local" development work on a Drupal site (office and home) and use Github as a central repository and the module Backup and Migrate to backup/restore the database when I alternate between my two locations. After a days work I backup the database and push my code to github. At home I can pull the code from Github and restore the database. This all works very good.

But... I use wampserver on both locations and at home it takes about 9 seconds to restore the database and the waiting time after every click on the site is less then a second. At the other location it takes 5 minutes to restore that same database and it takes 4-5 seconds before every page shows.
At work I just tried to re-install wampserver with no success... the site is just very slow. Both computers are new with 16 GB RAM.

Can anyone give me a hint on what to do, to speed up my slow wampserver?
This is all very strange, as the setup is identical on both computers.
I should mention that I have increased the realpath_cache_size on the slow computer without any change.

Comment: Are you sure the computers are identical? Maybe the first is 32-bit operating system and can use only 4Gb. Maybe different processors too

Comment: It could also be related to the disk on your computers, having a SSD improve web servers performances by a huge amount.

Comment: Ahh. the home computer indeed have a SSD disk... maybe that explains it. But I still need to figure out how to make the slow wampserver (much) faster. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

Following one of the the advices at [wamp-is-running-very-slow](https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/wamp-is-running-very-slow)

I was able to solve this problem.
The things that made the trick was to set the following line to "2":

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2... in the file my.ini (mysql settings).

And also to raise these buffers to 512M and 128M respectively:

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 512M

innodb_log_file_size = 128M

... in that same file. None of the other suggestions made any difference.

I hope this can help somebody.